# How to slove of card view android.view.InflateException error?

Tags: android

I am facing this issue

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32 in com.fintnessathome.fintnessathome:layout/bmr_calculator: Binary XML file line #32 in com.fintnessathome.fintnessathome:layout/bmr_calculator: Error inflating class androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32 in com.fintnessathome.fintnessathome:layout/bmr_calculator: Error inflating class androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Field.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

how to slove this problem ?

Comment: How do we supposed to know without code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.